# Maxima plot discrete data with 3 columns

Tags: plot, maxima

How to plot a discrete dataset with 3 or more columns? MWE is as follows:

```
/* Required essentially to create the data set */
eqn1: 4 - x^2 - 4*y^2$
eqn2: y^2 - x^2 + 1$
sol: rk([eqn1,eqn2],[x,y],[-1.25, 0.75],[t,0,4,0.2])$

/* My current workaround to plot (x vs t) and (y vs t) */
n : length(sol)$
/* Select the ith column and create separate lists */
tseries : makelist(sol[i][1], i, 1, n)$ 
xseries:  makelist(sol[i][2], i, 1, n)$ 
yseries:  makelist(sol[i][3], i, 1, n)$ 

plot2d([
    [discrete, tseries, xseries],
    [discrete, tseries, yseries]
], [legend,"x","y"] ,[xlabel,"t"], [ylabel,"x, y"],[style, 
[linespoints,2,2]],
[gnuplot_preamble,"set key box width 2 spacing 1.3 top left"])$
```

Is there a better solution to plot **without** creating the `tseries`, `xseries` and `yseries` lists?

Comment: Well, it seems like [sol[k][2], sol[k][3]] are the x and y coordinates corresponding to sol[k][1]. So maybe `plot2d([discrete, map (rest, sol)])` is enough.

Comment: @RobertDodier: This doesn't produce the same plots. The command `map(rest,sol)` produces the 2nd and 3rd column of the original data set. So I am guessing a variation of the above command will give the (1st and 2nd column) and (1st and 3rd column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, based on your comment I see what is the goal. Your solution can be made a little more brief although not a lot. Anyway, `map(lambda([txy], [txy[1], txy[2]]), sol)` produces the list of [t, x] points and `map(lambda([txy], [txy[1], txy[3]]), sol)` produces the list of [t, y] points. So with `sol` as given above, I find that

```
plot2d ([[discrete, map(lambda([txy], [txy[1], txy[2]]), sol)],
         [discrete, map(lambda([txy], [txy[1], txy[3]]), sol)]]);
```

has the desired output (omitting the plotting options for clarity).